# Multiple overlays with absolute position, fixed to their parent elements, as the same markup

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to create an overlay that stays on screen without shifting to the top when the page is scrolled, as a `position: fixed` element does. But I need to write it as the same code that will be repeated in `body` and any `div`, because every `overlay-wrap` element will be added dynamically with a jQuery script, that will be fired on some events.

The markup of an element that will be added from the script (the snippet is a simplified example, production code will be slightly different):

```
<div class="overlay-wrap">
    <div class="overlay flexbox">
        <div class="size-small shape-circle bgclr1 spc-small"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It stays the same in every `div.shape-square` and in the `body`.

So, I need my `overlay-wrap` element to behave as a `position: fixed` element (to stay on screen when the parent is being scrolled) and as a `position: relative` element (to shift with the parent when their grand-parent, e.g. `body`, is being scrolled).

```css
.size-medium {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.size-small {
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
}
.shape-square { border-radius: 0%; }
.shape-circle { border-radius: 50%; }
.bgclr0 { background-color: #e6ac0c; }
.bgclr1 { background-color: #0e6060; }
.bgclr2 { background-color: #e60c0c; }
.spc-small { margin: 5px; }
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.overlay-wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(192,192,192,0.3), rgba(255,0,0,0.3));
}
```

```html
<div class="size-medium shape-square bgclr0 spc-small">
    <div class="overlay-wrap">
        <div class="overlay flexbox">
            <div class="size-small shape-circle bgclr1 spc-small"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="size-medium shape-square bgclr0 spc-small">
    <div class="overlay-wrap">
        <div class="overlay flexbox">
            <div class="size-small shape-circle bgclr1 spc-small"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="size-medium shape-square bgclr0 spc-small">
    <div class="overlay-wrap">
        <div class="overlay flexbox">
            <div class="size-small shape-circle bgclr1 spc-small"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="size-medium shape-square bgclr0 spc-small">
    <div class="overlay-wrap">
        <div class="overlay flexbox">
            <div class="size-small shape-circle bgclr1 spc-small"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="size-medium shape-square bgclr0 spc-small">
    <div class="overlay-wrap">
        <div class="overlay flexbox">
            <div class="size-small shape-circle bgclr1 spc-small"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="size-medium shape-square bgclr0 spc-small">
    <div class="overlay-wrap">
        <div class="overlay flexbox">
            <div class="size-small shape-circle bgclr1 spc-small"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="size-medium shape-square bgclr0 spc-small">
    <div class="overlay-wrap">
        <div class="overlay flexbox">
            <div class="size-small shape-circle bgclr1 spc-small"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="size-medium shape-square bgclr0 spc-small">
    <div class="overlay-wrap">
        <div class="overlay flexbox">
            <div class="size-small shape-circle bgclr1 spc-small"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="size-medium shape-square bgclr0 spc-small">
    <div class="overlay-wrap">
        <div class="overlay flexbox">
            <div class="size-small shape-circle bgclr1 spc-small"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="size-medium shape-square bgclr0 spc-small">
    <div class="overlay-wrap">
        <div class="overlay flexbox">
            <div class="size-small shape-circle bgclr1 spc-small"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="overlay-wrap"> 
    <div class="overlay flexbox">
        <!-- This one should overlay every other element and be an overlay for the whole body -->
        <div class="size-small shape-circle bgclr1 spc-small"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there's an `.overlay-wrap` in the bottom, after every other orange square div with their own `overlay-wrap`s. It should overlay them all, but it doesn't.

How to do it with pure HTML/CSS or, if it's easier, with jQuery?

Main target browser is Internet Explorer 11. So, for example, I can't use `position: sticky`.

Comment: if an overlay is required means, why you would like to scroll? you can add a class to body and HTML when the overlay is active and for that class add CSS and add prop overflow hidden

Comment: @AravindS I can not do that because our app is being developed in Oracle APEX by a large team, and I am not responsible for behavior of `body` of the pages. It also could lead to more troubles, because some pages behave in very different ways than the others. I would like to make this in the most non-interferencial way possible.

Comment: can you try this CSS `.overlay-wrap { height: 100vh}`

Comment: @AravindS, it breaks everything :D

Comment: you removed `position:relative` from that?

Comment: @AravindS, It makes every `.overlay-wrap` too high, and I need it to adjust its sizes to every parent element. And those have multiple various sizes.

Comment: @AravindS Yes and No, tried both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176045/discussion-between-aravind-s-and-velfr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best existing solution would be an additional CSS style with a direct child selector and `position:fixed`, like this:

```
body>.overlay-wrap{position:fixed;}
```